# How can I find out the status of a statement in chargify? I.e. if it is paid of not?

Tags: documentation, status, billing, invoice, chargify

How can I find out the status of a statement in chargify? I.e. if it is paid of not?

I found [this](https://reference.chargify.com/v1/statements/statements-intro) documentation. It says:

> Chargify Statements give you and your customers a breakdown of Subscription charges, payments, credits, and activity on a period-by-period basis. A Statement is similar to an “Invoice” because it is marked as currently paid or unpaid. Statements display all account activity for a specific usage period.

So, I would expect there to be a marking field which would tell me if the statement is paid, but I can not find such field. I tried to find the field in the documentation I linked above and in the query result I have in my system.

In my system I tried to rely on the `ending_balance_in_cents` field. I.e. when it is 0 I deem the statement as paid, otherwise as unpaid. But the problem is that the Chargify does not think the same way. It has the following statement:

[image]

As you can see the statement is Paid, even though the Ending Balance is not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the payment came in after the statement closed.  Try looking at the settled_at date and see if that helps determine if the statement is now paid.

https://reference.chargify.com/v1/statements/statements-intro#statement-output-attributes